# PDO Problems with 0 and NULL

Tags: php, sql

I have a customer table that I cannot change. It has a varchar field, that contains either NULL or 5.

I am trying to change that to a 1/0 (tinyint 1) in my field.

```
if ($row['varfield'] == '7') {
    $row['varfield'] = 1;
} else {
    $row['varfield'] = 0;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->execute(array($row['varfield']));
```

However I am getting the error in my SQL saying that the col1 cannot be nullable...

Comment: Well, what type is the column?

Comment: It's a tinyint (4) with default (0)

Comment: Did you update the table to change all the `NULL` values to `0` first?

Comment: default (0) as numeric 0? IF error says "cannot be nullable", then it must try to add value as NULL. If thats wanted then you should set "default NULL". Mabye it does not like that you give variables as integers, you could try give them as strings like $row['varfield'] = '0';

Comment: Try `var_dump($row['varfield'])` just before statment to verify that you are trying to insert proper value..

Answer (score 1):

> However I am getting the error in my SQL saying that the col1 cannot be nullable...

So set the column to be nullable in the database.

Comment: I think he/she wants to change the column from a nullable varchar to to be a non-null boolean (`tinyint(1)`).

Comment: Well the goal is to store it as a boolean.

Comment: one month later i have try to use "tinyint" in PDO but i havn't found solution, i juste used "enum" with values '0','1' or "int"